# Writing a String to Hrefs but ignore certain classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code here that add's a string to every href just like intended. I am trying to alter to create an IF inside my while loop to ignore hrefs with a class of "location-button" and "phonebox"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        <?php
        oneToAnother(64, 'gclid');
        oneToAnother(32, 'utm_source');
        oneToAnother(33, 'utm_medium');
        oneToAnother(34, 'utm_campaign');

        ?>
        var a = jQuery('.wrapper a');
        for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            var link = jQuery(a[i]).attr('href');
            jQuery(a[i]).attr('href', link + '<?=$string?>');
        }
    }, 1500);
});
</script>
```

Have tried adding the IF in my php with mixed results.

Add string to hrefs of all a tags without class of "phonebox" or "location-button". A tags that have "phonebox" or "location-button" would not get a string appended to their href.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use jQuery for excluding them right away?

```
var a = jQuery('.wrapper a').not('.phonebox, .location-button');
```

Comment:  dur hur... i forgot all about .not selector.